# Allow text to be dropped into textbox but not written by user

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to make a text box where text can be dragged/dropped into but where the user cannot write text into themselves.

The pseudo code would be as follows:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if( text is not dropped )
    {
        txtInstructionReg.Text = "";
    }
}
```

Comment: You could make the textbox read-only.  It could still be a drop target.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that you can use events in exactly the way that you're looking to.  Instead, I'd suggest handling each event separately to allow/disallow the actions that you wish to control.

For instance, with your example I would have handlers for both of the events that could happen for the textbox.  The event that handles typed text would delete the new input and perhaps display a message to the user that effectively says "You can't do that".  Then have the drag/drop handler accept text and put it in the textbox.

Comment: is there a handler for typed text?

Comment: You didn't mention what framework you're working with (WPF, Windows Forms, etc) but I'd imagine there is.  What framework are you using?

Comment: I'm using Windows forms

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.textbox?view=netframework-4.7.2#events looks like there are `KeyUp` and `KeyDown` events.  Handling those might work, I'm not that familiar with WPF.  There is also `TextInput` that might also work to disable typing.  It'd probably take a little extra digging to figure out which events you need to handle to allow/disallow all of the functionality that you want to, but it's there.  I don't think that it'd be too difficult given your initial ask.

Comment: I'd first try to make it read-only, then check if D&D still works.